# Some sum of two elements exceeds a third one in a finite multiset with bounded values

Tags: pigeonhole-principle, multisets

For a multiset $S = \{ a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_k \}$ where $k = 13$ and $1 \leqslant a < 32$, prove that there exists a subset $s = \{ a_i, a_j, a_k \}$ such that each sum of two elements exceeds the third, i.e. $a_i+a_j>a_k$ and $a_j+a_k>a_i$ and $a_i+a_k>a_j$.

I was wondering how to solve this using Pigeon-Hole Principle. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: People will pay more attention to your post if you properly format your math formulas using mathjax.

Comment: Hint: if there exists $x$ such that $x\le a_i,a_j,a_k<2x$, then all three sum inequalities will be satisfied.

Comment: thank you. But I can't figure how to put that into a pigeon-hole perspective?